# R data.table aggregate data

Tags: r, data.table

I used to do data aggregation using `aggregate`, how can I do something similar in `data.table`?

Say I generate the data like this:

```
data <- data.table("a"=sample(1:100, 100),
                   "b"=sample(1:100, 100),
                   "c"=sample(1:100, 100),
                   "d"=sample(1:100, 100),
                   "metric"=rnorm(100))
```

I used to do this: `aggregate(metric~a+b, data=data, sum)`. What is the equivalent way to do this in `data.table`? I tried `data[, total:=sum(metric), by=list(a,b)]`, but the other columns are not dropped.

Comment: I think you're looking for: `data[, list(metric=sum(metric)), by=list(a,b)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the result :

```
data[, total:=sum(metric), by=list(a,b)][, c('a','b','metric')]
```

Another way to get the same result( I think it is faster) , is to use `dcast`:

```
reshape2::dcast(data,a+b~.,fun=sum,value.var="metric")
```